# C# Task Factory

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Hi I have code like below in a for loop.  It is in a for loop because the number of times it needs to be run can vary dependent on how many items the user has added.

```
var taskList = new List<Task<IEnumerable<MyObject>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfBatches; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(variableA, variableB));
    taskList.Add(task);
}

//Wait for all the tasks to complete 
Task.WaitAll(taskList.Cast<Task>().ToArray());

return taskList.SelectMany(x => x.Result);
```

Is there a better way I can run these tasks in Parallel?  I was thinking about a parallel for each loop but because the number of iterations of the loops isn't fixed I don't think I can use a parallel for each

There isn't necessarily a problem with the code.  However if I have 10,000 items inputted it takes about 18 minutes and I was thinking if I could run the Tasks in parallel it may return faster.  If 10,000 items are inputted the number of batches will be 10,000/25 = 400

The actuall code in MyMethod calls a 3rd party external service to return data based on data entered by user

Comment: Is there any problem with this code?

Comment: There is a `Parallel.For` too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - read the question properly.

Comment: You could use a `Parallel.For` as suggested by @ScottChamberlain but will you gain any benefit in the time taken for the `numberOfBatches` to be split into separate running batches? Cost of building the batched collection to run vs. benefit of running them in parallel.

Comment: The code seems fine, and if it serves its purpose, why do you want to change it? Is there a bug or something you are trying to workaround?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - some edits added to the question

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to go bananas and spawn a new thread per task like this. it works in some cases, but in others it's not worth the overhead. you might wanna considder partitioning the jobs into smaller lists of jobs and then run the lists in parallel (using Parallel.For or something similar). Also, prefer Task.Run over Task.Factory.StartNew() in all cases except some edge cases (that you'd probably know about if you need to consider them).

Comment: Are you looking for - explanation why some particular call to `Parallel.ForEach`/`For` did not work, way to estimate how long your calls should take, figuring out if your code is CPU or IO bound, something else? Side note: The real solution is to rewrite your `MyMethod` code to use async/await and properly call remote service asynchronously... but I doubt anyone would consider it as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Processing a list in parallel is about the easiest of parallel algorithms there is:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, numOfBatches)
.Select(_ => MyMethod(variableA, variableB))
.ToList();
```

It is a code smell to create unbounded numbers of tasks because this can lead to resource exhaustion and the code is clumsy.

Comment: what is the _ in the .Select for?

Comment: Also my method returns an IEnumerable<MyObject> - I dont see how the code snippet about can do that

Comment: _ is a variable name. It's the unused number from the ParallelEnumerable.Range. You can append a SelectMany(x => x) to flatten the lists into one.